# Stop TOUCHMOVE event when finger is not on the element anymore (but still pressed)

Tags: javascript, events, controls, touch-event, touchmove

I have a div(#parent) with 4 child elements inside. 
The idea is when I touch one of < span > elements and move finger I fire the event(touchmove) and when I move finger outside of the current < span > (while still pressing) the event should stop.

I tried to get this work with checking if I touch < span > or other element but with no luck. Once I press and move I cannot stop event before I release the finger.

```
document.querySelector("#parent").addEventListener('touchmove', (e) => {
    console.log(`pressed ${e.target.getAttribute('data-dir')}`)
});

<div id="parent">
   <span data-dir="3">&uarr;</span>
   <span data-dir="0">&rarr;</span>
   <span data-dir="1">&darr;</span>
   <span data-dir="2">&larr;</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First, you could use `document.elementFromPoint()` API to judge if your finger is inside or outside of the `<span>`.
2. Then, you could stop the event by `removeEventListener`. During the moving if finger is outside of `<span>`, just remove the listener.

Like this:

```
const $el = document.querySelector("#parent")
$el.addEventListener('touchstart', function startHandler(e) {
  $el.addEventListener('touchmove', function moveHandler(e) {
      if (document.elementFromPoint(e.touches[0].clientX, e.touches[0].clientY).tagName !== 'SPAN') {
        $el.removeEventListener('touchmove', moveHandler)
      }) else {
        // do your things
      }
  });
  $el.addEventListener('touchend', function endHandler(e){
    // remove the listeners to avoid mutiple listeners
    $el.removeEventListener('touchstart', startHandler)
    $el.removeEventListener('touchmove', moveHandler)
    $el.removeEventListener('touchend', endHandler)
  })
})
```